# When is "-less" used, and when is "-free" used?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, suffixes

When is the suffix "-less" used, and when is the suffix "-free" used?

My initial assumption was that "-free" is used when the absence of something is good, such as "care-free", and "-less" is used when the absence of something is bad, such as "careless".

But while looking up [-less](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-less#English) in Wiktionary, I came across words like "blameless" and "cordless". If the above logic were used, it'd be "blame-free" (the word gets some google hits, but nowhere near as many) and "cord-free".

Is there any logic to when "-less" and "-free" is used?

Comment: Here is an illustration of the difference: If you walk through a swarm of insects, you will remain bite-free only if they are themselves biteless. Even if they were to bite, you would remain pain-free only if the bites were painless. Notice how poor a fit, if any, is obtained by swapping those.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, but why are fish fillets [boneless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneless_Fish), whereas dealcoholised wine is [alcohol-free](http://www.alcoholfree.co.uk/)? In both cases you have to specifically ***remove*** something, to get the thing you want. Besides, you can be *blameless* or *blame-free* - makes no difference to me.

Comment: _Smokeless_ and _smoke-free_ are used in different ways: smoke-free = with no smoke in the atmosphere: smoke-free hospitals
smokeless = giving rise to little or no smoke; smoke-free: smokeless fuel; smokeless environment. As usual, it's not clear-cut. Probably, _smokeless zone_ used the term partially in a transferred sense, _a zone where only smokeless fuels may be used_. My perception is that the - -free suffix is more productive than the -less one.

Comment: At the very least, see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=78KFCIHtJS4C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=what's+the+difference+between+the+suffix+less+and+free&source=bl&ots=j83nIoA6z2&sig=-WM_d7Kdmz5cYRoU0P44F6SSig4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e-qwUKqQOMG8yAHf1YHgAQ&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=what's%20the%20difference%20between%20the%20suffix%20less%20and%20free&f=false), [here](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Recent+derivatives+with+the+suffix+-less%3A+a+change+in+progress+within...-a092803254), and [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv33.shtml).

Comment: I guess -less refers to the nature of something, which can't be changed while -free indicates that something can be present or absent at one's will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the logic for when to use either suffix revolves around the denotation of the text you are writing.  Use **-less** when a sentence refers to the absence of something formerly present, for example, a cordless phone.  Use -**free** when a sentence refers to something that was never present, for example a carefree child.

I use the denotation because while -free tends to have positive connotations, -less can have either positive or negative connotations.  But using the above rules based on context works in most situations.

Comment: We say “boneless”, but the bone previously exists, it is removed afterwards. Why don’t we say “bone free”?

Comment: I think the accepted answer is just wrong and this is a matter of convention.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction (by convention) between blame-less and blame-free.

An innocent child, assumed to be incapable of malice, would be **blame-less** in the event of some catastrophe befalling the family. By contrast, its father (who might have been thought responsible by some) could be adjudged **blame-free** when another explanation is found.

On the other hand, the mobile telephone that can be used in a hands-free manner would not sell  very well if advertised as being hands-less.